# Error "dlsym(0x7f8ffd410a90, Init_bigdecimal): symbol not found" on Mac M1 Big Sur

Tags: cocoapods, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I've faced this issue while using pod install on Macbook M1

abc@MacBook-Air ~ % arch -x86_64 pod install

Traceback (most recent call last):
16: from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' 15: from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in` load'
14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>' 13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in` <top (required)>'
10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' 7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.5/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:5:in` <top (required)>'
4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlsym(0x7f8ffd410a90, Init_bigdecimal): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle (LoadError)
abc@MacBook-Air ~ %

Please give me some advices

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is a miss in bigdecimal under gem (bundle not found)
So, to solve this issue, you just need to install this gem.

run this command on terminal:
sudo gem install bigdecimal

It should work.
In general issue like this in the future -> Just check what is in the log.
Here it's
dlsym(0x7f8ffd410a90, Init_bigdecimal): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle

Then the keyword to search is about gems, bigdecimal
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, but only with `pod update`, weirdly `pod install` was fine!

Try to install ffi :

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

And then retry:

```
pod install
```

I hope it will be okay for you.

From GitHub https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70796

**EDIT:** Don't forget to set "Open with Rosetta" in your terminal app.